# Size scale field - QGIs Pisa 2.10-1 Where did it go?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.10

I've been scaling symbol sizes in QGIS using the size-scale field under the "advanced" option on the properties-style dialog.  We just upgraded to Pisa and now it's gone - anyone know where it went?  I'm tempted to roll back to 2.8 if I can't find it.

[image: This is the 2.8 dialog, with the scale-sized points in the background]

Answer (score 7):

The size-scale advanced option and the data-defined settings button have been replaced by "data defined override" buttons which you might already be familiar with from the labeling dialog. This is how to scale the symbols:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I don't think I ever would have found it.

Comment: I found this dialog yesterday, but have had issue getting fair results from it. Is there a tutorial or such that might go into detail from this menu?

Answer (score 0):

Layer Properties then on top left, change single symbol to graduated. 
My points also disappeared after I selected the columns and clicked Apply, the step that is required in between is to click classify first after you have chosen your breaks. Then when you click apply they stay where they are supposed to.